# how to get an svg pattern to properly align to the slope of a line its applied to

Tags: svg

I want to make patterned svg lines but can't find how to make the defined pattern path slope along with the line path it's being applied as the stroke to.

the pattern stays aligned to the x and y axis here, is there not a simple argument to get it to be sloped along the line path right?

```html
<svg width="400" height="400">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="pattern" x="0" y="0" width="16" height="20" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
      <path d="M 0 0 L 3 3 L 0 6 L 12 6 L 15 3 L 12 0" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>
    </pattern>
  </defs>

<line x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke:url(#pattern);stroke-width:20" />
</svg>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bionicgoat/6zsfj5hp/18/

Comment: you may use patternTransform to rotate the pattern to your needs like this: `patternTransform="rotate(45)"`

Answer (score 1):

Because the <pattern> `id` is tied to the <line> `stroke="url(#id)"`, you need to do same extra work and create a pattern for every line if you want **multiple** lines with the same pattern

[image]

```html
<svg-pattern-line>
  <defs>
    <pattern width="20" height="15" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <path d="m0 0 3 3-3 3 12 0 3-3-3-3"></path>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <style>
    line { stroke-width:10 }
  </style>
  <line x1="0"   y1="0"   x2="200" y2="0"               ></line>
  <line x1="0"   y1="0"   x2="200" y2="120" fill="red"  ></line>
  <line x1="180" y1="10"  x2="20"  y2="160" fill="green"></line>
  <line x1="180" y1="180" x2="20"  y2="16"  fill="blue" ></line>
</svg-pattern-line>

<script>
  customElements.define('svg-pattern-line', class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      setTimeout(() => { // wait till innerHTML is parsed by Browser
        this.innerHTML = `<svg width="400" viewBox="0 0 200 200">${this.innerHTML}</svg>`;
        this.defs      = this.querySelector("defs");
        this.pattern   = this.querySelector("pattern");
        this.querySelectorAll("line").forEach(line=>{
          let attr    = (a) => line.getAttribute(a);
          let angle   = (180 / Math.PI) * Math.atan2(attr("y2") - attr("y1"), attr("x2") - attr("x1"));
          let pattern = this.defs.appendChild(this.pattern.cloneNode(true));
          pattern.id  = "P" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1e8);
          pattern.setAttribute("patternTransform", `rotate(${angle})`);
          pattern.setAttribute("fill"  , attr("fill"));
          pattern.setAttribute("stroke", attr("fill"));
             line.setAttribute("stroke",`url(#${pattern.id})`);
        })
      })
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate the line using transform/rotate. Then the pattern also rotates.

```html
<svg width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="pattern" x="0" y="0" width="16" height="6"
      patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
      <path d="M 0 0 L 3 3 L 0 6 L 12 6 L 15 3 L 12 0 Z"
        stroke="black" stroke-width="0"/>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
<line x1="0" y1="3" x2="200" y2="3" transform="rotate(45)"
  stroke="url(#pattern)" stroke-width="6" />
</svg>
```